# Does the Python SDK for CosmosDB not allow for token/credential auth?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The examples given in the python SDK to access a cosmosdb account only use the masterkey; is it possible access tables or SQL collections using `from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import MSIAuthentication` or something similar (which for example allows for MSI token auth into keyvault) for auth into cosmos?

(obviously python could manually implement REST API for token auth, just wondering if SDK support is there)

Answer (score 1):

No, Azure Cosmos doesn't support AAD based auth yet, so none of the SDKs support this. A common pattern I've seen to avoid having it in a config file/env variable is to use Azure KeyVault to store the master key, then use MSI to access that key in-memory and pass it into the client constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported on Cosmos DB now. You can try it across all [SDKs now](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac), You can check the samples for different SDKS.

Azure Cosmos DB exposes a built-in role-based access control (RBAC) system
which lets you to Authenticate your data requests with an Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) identity.